# Copying checkbox value with dynamic ID to hidden input value using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, copy

I'm sooo... close but am stuck on one tiny thing that's probably really simple for you. The idea is to add the value of each checkbox to the hidden field's value.

The moment I add a second (or more forms) with their own variable ID's, it falls apart. I know the first part of the jQuery code works but I don't know how to get `loader_id` into here.

```
$('#fileset-'+ loader_id +' input').click(updateFileField);
```

I *think* that is where I'm messing up because if I hard code the id here the rest works beautifully.

The following is the full code and can also be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/techbased/fXMrj/50/)

```
<div id="fileset-1" class="fileset">
<input type="checkbox" value="set1">
<input type="checkbox" value="set2">
<input type="checkbox" value="set3">
</div>  
File 1 <input type="text" val="" id="file-1" class="filestosend" /><br />

<div id="fileset-2" class="fileset">
<input type="checkbox" value="seta">
<input type="checkbox" value="setb">
<input type="checkbox" value="setc">
</div> 
File 2 <input type="text" val="" id="file-2" class="filestosend" />​
```

Here's the jQuery portion

```
 function updateFileField() {

 var allVals = [];
 var loader_id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').replace('fileset-', '');
     $('#fileset-' + loader_id + ' :checked').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
     });         
     $('#file-' + loader_id ).val(allVals);
  }
 $(function() {
     $('#fileset-'+ loader_id +' input').click(updateFileField);

});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to be using loader_id before it's been defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that you've been looking for?

```
$(".fileset :checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var div = $(this).parent();
    var id = div.attr("id").split("-")[1];
    var values = [];
    div.find(":checked").each(function() {
        values.push(this.value);
    });
    $("#file-" + id).val(values.join(","));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fXMrj/52/

Comment: Yes! Thank you the demo worked great and is what I am hoping to achieve. Thanks for teaching me an alternative way I understand your code a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the following part `loader_id` is undefined.

```
$(function() {
     $('#fileset-'+ loader_id +' input').click(updateFileField);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I realized after a while it is undefined I just didn't know how to define it as using `var loader_id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').replace('fileset-', '');` didn't work.